# Create Vips Image from Numpy RGB array for big images

Tags: python, numpy, vips

I was trying to output a large, generated image with PIL/Pillow, but it breaks when the image sizes get bigger.

So based on things I read on SO, I'm trying to use Vips.

My generated data is a numpy array of RGB values.  I want to convert this to a image in Vips so I can save it.  However I cannot work out how to get the pixel data into Vips.

```
import numpy
import gi
gi.require_version('Vips', '8.0')
from gi.repository import Vips

WIDTH=32768
HEIGHT=32768
UCHAR=Vips.BandFormat.UCHAR

# Create an RGB black image
black_space = numpy.zeros( ( WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3 ), dtype=numpy.uint8 )

# this doesn't work
vips_image = Vips.Image.new_from_memory( black_space, WIDTH, HEIGHT, bands=3, format=UCHAR )
vips_image.write_to_file( "space_32k.tiff" )
```

Of course it fails with the error when creating the Vips image:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bad_vips.py", line 14, in <module>
    vips_image = Vips.Image.new_from_memory( black_space, WIDTH, HEIGHT, bands=3, format=UCHAR )
TypeError: Item 0: expected int argument
```

Is there a way of transforming the numpy array so it works with Vips?

I also tried passing `black_space.data`, but then I get:

```
NotImplementedError: Item 0: multi-dimensional sub-views are not implemented
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the old libvips Python interface -- there's a newer one now which is quite a bit better:

https://github.com/libvips/pyvips

Docs here:

https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/

There's [a section](https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/intro.html#numpy-and-pil) about linking libvips and numpy. Your example would be:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvips
    
array = np.zeros((100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
image = pyvips.Image.new_from_array(array)
image.write_to_file("huge.tif")
```

Comment: Fixed it!  Thanks for that.

Comment: Glad it's working. I tried to update the question you based this on as well.

Comment: For grayscale images (only one channel):
`linear = image_matrix.astype(np.uint8).reshape(-1)`


`im = pyvips.Image.new_from_memory(linear.data, image_matrix.shape[1], image_matrix.shape[0], bands=1, format="uchar")`


`im.write_to_file('out.bmp')`